# Настройка сервера Azure для SignalR

Tags: azure

Пытаюсь запустить self-hosted SignalR приложение сервер на вируталке Azure

```
const string ServerURI = "http://<myip>:8080";

SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
```

Сервер не создается.

Если создать локальный сервер то все хорошо

```
const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080";
```

Входящее правило для порта создано.

На отдельной VPS все отлично работает, а на Azure никак...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было создать сетевую группу безопасности и там добавить нужный порт.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg